# two javascripts won't execute on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, head

I have two jquery javascripts (scrollpane and last.fm one). However, whichever one is posted later in the `<head>` is the one that executes and shows up on the page and the other one disappears. I don't know how to fix this. Here is my head code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<!--LASTFM-->
    <link href="css/engage.lastfm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/engage.lastfm.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        // Begin jQuery goodness
        $('div#lastfm').lastFM({
        username: 'angrypink',
        apikey: '255b0123e857aa3f6fd52a76b70ec15d',
        number: 2,
        artSize: 'medium',
        onComplete: function(){
        }
        });
        // End jQuery goodness
        });
    </script>

<!--JSCROLL-->
    <link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" id="sourcecode">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var $images = $(".tumblr img")
          , imageCount = $images.length
          , counter = 0;
          $images.one("load",function(){
             counter++;
             if (counter == imageCount) {
                 $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
         } 
        }).each(function () {
            if (this.complete) {
                $(this).trigger("load");
            }
        });
        });
    </script>

</head>
```

Comment: All the jquery ready function will excute, they don't overlap but if one of document ready fails it will prevent other from executing.. can you put alert or console.log on both and check

Comment: how do I go about doing that?

Comment: I went into chrome and opened javascript console on the page. here's what came up:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'lastFM' index.html:25
(anonymous function) index.html:25
c.extend.ready jquery.min.js:26
L jquery.min.js:33`
`event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery.js:5374`

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ alert("First: I am called") }) and same in second alert("Second: I am called"), and check your console log for errors

Comment: You have two different (and possibly incompatible) versions of jQuery, one of which is loaded twice. This is a mess. _Understand_ what you're loading, then tidy this up.

Comment: If I remove the jquery 1.4 jquery then the last.fm script doesn't load. And if I remove the 1.10 jquery then all my other javascripts don't load :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a mistake : You have multiple definition of jquery :

```
      <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Try to just put this one time, keep this one : `<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`

Because is local one, and not depending on google

Try to clean a bit because multiple definition of jquery can create error

Comment: When i remove the 1.4 jquery then the last.fm code doesn't work but if I remove the 1.10 query then all the other javascripts on the page don't work!

Comment: did you include jquery on the top of the script ? before to inclure other .js?

Comment: That worked like a charm actually, thank you so so much!!! I didn't know you had to put jquery all the way on the top of the `<head>`